# view.goTo map renders blank arcgis

Tags: javascript, vue.js, arcgis

I am working on an arcgis map, I'm trying to update the map center by calling goTo() on my mapview but for some reason the map just changes to be blank and never updates, I am logging the new coordinates and they are correct.

I am using the reference docs here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html

Can someone with some arcgis experience help me out. I know this isn't an issue with my code specifically but it might be an issue with vue and component rendering as it relates to arcgis

so far I have tried
- getting rid of props and updating everything within the component locally
- using keys to force re-render the component

as an interesting note, if I just enter in some magic numbers for my new location the map updates correctly, however when i use some function to get the location and then pass it in, it does not work and just shows as a blank map

my app.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <web-map v-bind:centerX="lat" v-bind:centerY="long" ref="map"/>

        <div class="center">
          <b-button class="btn-block" @click="updateCenter()" variant="primary">My Location</b-button>
        </div>
    </div>


</template>

<script>
import WebMap from './components/webmap.vue';

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: { WebMap }, 
    data(){
      return{
        lat: null,
        long: null,
      }
    },
    methods:{
      updateCenter(){
        this.$refs.map.getLocation()
      }
    },
};
</script>
```

my map component

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';

export default {
  name: 'web-map',
  data: function(){
    return{
      X: -118,
      Y: 34,

    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('new data',this.X,this.Y)

    // lazy load the required ArcGIS API for JavaScript modules and CSS
    loadModules(['esri/Map', 'esri/views/MapView'], { css: true })
    .then(([ArcGISMap, MapView]) => {
      const map = new ArcGISMap({
        basemap: 'topo-vector'
      });

      this.view = new MapView({
        container: this.$el,
        map: map,
        center: [-118,34],   ///USE PROPS HERE FOR NEW CENTER
        zoom: 8
      });
    });
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    if (this.view) {
      // destroy the map view
      this.view.container = null;
    }
  },


  methods:{
    showPos(pos){
        console.log('new location',pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude) 
        this.view.goTo({center:[pos.coords.latitude,pos.coords.longitude]})  
      },


      getLocation(){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPos);
          } else { 
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
          }
      },
  }

};

</script>
```

Comment: Could you set up a codesandbox.io with what you have?

Comment: @tao here is a sandbox for what I have https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-cerf-wjnqk?file=/src/components/webmap.vue

Comment: I have tried returning pos.coords from showPos but I get an undefined value, so I tried to make the updates inside showPos() itself. I am able to log the coordinates correctly from inside the function so I figured I should be able to pass them to view.goTo()

Comment: i was wrong there. it's ok to place a handler fn there and it doesn't need a `return` value. It needs to handle the coords, and yours did. I added an answer with a working example. Could probably be cleaner, but I'm not familiar with ArcGIS.

Comment: `this.$refs.map.getLocation()`  will never work. `this.$refs.map` is the child element's `$el`, a DOM element, which doesn't have a `getLocation` method. The method is defined on the child element's Vue instance which, among others, has a reference to that particular DOM element, in `$el`.

Comment: Did you somehow find the solution?
I face the same problem. The problem occurs especially when using view.goto () with GoToOptions (duration longer than default).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that works:

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-glitter-39wpe?file=/src/App.vue

I made it from scratch, only taking small bits from yours and combining them with some examples from ArcGIS (which I'm not familiar with, at all).

One thing to note is that the `.goTo({center: [lat, long]})` didn't work as expected: it kept centering in the middle of some ocean.
I then imported Point from `esri` and passed the `center` as `new Point(long, lat)`, which seems to produce the expected result. Since it works, I haven't looked further, but I guess it should be doable without the conversion. You probably need to pass in the coordinates system or something along these lines.

As far as I can tell, what's wrong in your example is the way you try to pass data down from parent to child. You expect `this.$refs.map` to be a Vue instance, but it's not. It's a DOM element. It's basically the Vue instance's `$el`. Accessing child methods from parent instance is not so straight forward. 
Another thing to notice is that, even though you bind `centerX` and `centerY` on child in your example, you never seem to use them (but I guess that's just a left over from when you tried with props !?).

Anyways, in my example, I chose to simply update the coords prop of the children while having a `watch` fn to handle re-centering.

Comment: thank you, that's very interesting that you had to make an instance of a new Point to make it work. I had suspected that it was some kind of type issue since magic numbers seemed to work but my returned data would not. I too am brand new to arcgis and they have a lot of diverse documentation thank you for helping me sort this out :)

Answer (score 1):

Switch:

```
this.view = new MapView({
    container: this.$el,
    map: map,
    center: [-118,34],   ///USE PROPS HERE FOR NEW CENTER
    zoom: 8
  });
```

to

```
this.view = new MapView({
        container: this.$el,
        map: map });
this.view.center.longitude = -118;
this.view.center.latitude = 34;
this.view.zoom = 8;
```

The other answer by Tao has the long/latitude backwards in the .goTo({center: []}) method call, which is why it goes to the ocean: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#goTo